# Is this event referenced in the Old or New Testament?

Tags: verse-identification

When Jesus was alive, there was an earthquake in Alasehir in 17 AD. Quantitative records of this earthquake are very scarce. I wonder if there are any records of this event being pointed out in the Old or New Testaments.

For example, while there are a few verses in the Qur'an that overlap with the 1556 Shensi earthquake, I can interpret the Alasehir earthquake within the scope of the destruction of the clans.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ala%C5%9Fehir

Comment: Earthquakes are common. Why would an earthquake so far from where the events of the Gospels happen rate a mention?? Also, *nothing* at that time was mentioned in the Gospels - they skip from one short story when Jesus was 12 to when he was around 30.

Comment: the bible is not a history book, though it does contain history

Comment: Scientists claim that this earthquake is the disaster of the century. It is clear that some of the apostles also went to the Aegean region. Why should we immediately claim that this issue has not been addressed?

Comment: At the very least, there should be a strong analogy.

Comment: Also, if you look at this link, you will understand that there is a contradiction. From the same source and translation is required: [https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/1556_%C5%9Eensi_depremi?wprov=sfla1](https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/1556_%C5%9Eensi_depremi?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: @Lesley I didn't say there was a strong analogy between them. If I had said that I was investigating the fatalistic effects of this earthquake, the question would have been deleted with a majority of votes. The earthquake happened in the time of the Lydians, the Lydians invented money, and after the events in the New Testament, the rule of the Lydians is coming to an end. Taxpayers are glorified at this time. Even the center of this earthquake could not be determined and it affected the entire Aegean region of Anatolia. If there is a verse on this, it would be better to act early.

Comment: The Old Testament was completed a few years before 400 BCE.  The events of the New Testament relate to the life of Jesus, his birth, a short account of him in the temple when he was 12 years old and then his ministry of just over 3 years.

Comment: The only earthquake mentioned in NT was at the crucifixion which was on 3rd April AD 33.

Comment: Confirmation of the earthquake at the time of the crucifixion of Jesus in Jerusalem found here (but copyright protected): https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2012AM/webprogram/Paper204688.html#:~:text=The%20persistent%2033%20A.D.%20seismite,western%20side%20of%20Temple%20Mount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earthquake that happened in 17 A.D. in Alaşehir, which was previously known as Philadelphia, is not mentioned in the New Testament.  However, the Apostle Paul did visit that place (and many other towns in that part of Asia) during his missionary journeys in the second half of the first century.

In Revelation 3:7-13 the Apostle John mentions the Christian church in Philadelphia, but there is no reference to any earthquake.  Indeed, why should there be, given the event you mention happened before the Gospel accounts or the other books of the New Testament were written?

The Turkish name Alaşehir, is first attested in the memoir of the 13th-century historian Ibn Bibi. (Encyclopaedia of Islam, 3rd edition) [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ala%C5%9Fehir)

I can’t see how the events of the 1556 Shensi earthquake overlap with a few verses in the Qur’an given that the Qur’an was written circa 650.

EDIT: [This article](https://www.gotquestions.org/church-in-Philadelphia.html) discusses what Christ Jesus had to say about the Christian church in Philadelphia.

[This article](https://www.gotquestions.org/temple-veil-torn.html) explains the significance of the earthquake that rent the heavy veil in the Temple in Jerusalem at the time Jesus died.

Comment: [5] I read the article. It shows that multiple tectonic movements are triggered at the same time. Kahramanmaras earthquake is quite similar to the Alasehir earthquake but floor liquation caused the earthquake center to disappear and accelerated tectonic movements. It is enough reason for the disaster of the century because the structures of that region could survive in very severe earthquakes at that time. I don't think this earthquake will be routinely repeated. I guess we can't get more data with this reason.

Comment: [4] In the Qur'an, very strong earthquakes are likened to hell: [At-Tawba 109](https://qurano.gitlab.io/en/9-at-tawba/verse-109/)

Comment: The Gospels of Matthew and Luke speak of earthquakes. Confirmation of earthquakes in the region of Jerusalem on April 3, A.D 33 can be found here in this paper (all copyright protected): https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2012AM/webprogram/Paper204688.html#:~:text=The%20persistent%2033%20A.D.%20seismite,western%20side%20of%20Temple%20Mount.

Comment: [4] There were no influential external factors other than the Turks to prevent the Chinese empires from continuing their traditions for thousands of years. The fact that the Shanxi people have a primitive understanding of urbanization is paradigmatically compatible with this situation. That question on everyone's mind; How can the Qur'an know the pace of development of technology and industry?

Comment: @fkybrd - This site is about Christianity, not Islam or earthquakes or history.

Comment: Of course. I just thought I was helping you understand. Thank you for answering a question that I think is relevant to Christian history. Since the Old Testament, the New Testament and the Qur'an are very similar to each other in terms of their reading, I have given an understandable reading example. It's very political, ironic and tragicomic that you don't want to know your history. Good day.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this earthquake was a result of Christ giving up the ghost

[‭‭Mark 15:37-38 KJV‬‬](https://bible.com/bible/1/mrk.15.37.KJV)

> <sup>**37**</sup> And Jesus cried with a loud voice, and gave up the ghost. <sup>**38**</sup> And the veil of the temple was rent in twain from the top to the bottom.

‭‭[Matthew 27:50-54 KJV](https://bible.com/bible/1/mat.27.50.KJV)‬

> <sup>**50**</sup> Jesus, when he had cried again with a loud voice, yielded up the ghost. <sup>**51**</sup> And, behold, the veil of the temple was rent in twain from the top to the bottom; and the earth did quake, and the rocks rent; <sup>**52**</sup> and the graves were opened; and many bodies of the saints which slept arose, <sup>**53**</sup> and came out of the graves after his resurrection, and went into the holy city, and appeared unto many. <sup>**54**</sup> Now when the centurion, and they that were with him, watching Jesus, saw the earthquake, and those things that were done, they feared greatly, saying, Truly this was the Son of God.

Comment: Even if there are differences in the books of Matthew and Mark, the Old Testament should not be overlooked if we consider the verses according to their place in the wider time. I thınk that they have chronologic position.

Comment: Confirmation of the earthquake in Jerusalem at the time Jesus was crucified found here (but copyright protected): https://gsa.confex.com/gsa/2012AM/webprogram/Paper204688.html#:~:text=The%20persistent%2033%20A.D.%20seismite,western%20side%20of%20Temple%20Mount.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.